# How to create an outlook extention which consumes data from azure

Tags: azure, outlook

I'm not sure where to start looking for this - I need to create an outlook extension which gets data via an API from Azure.

Bascially, when my client clicks on an email, the system makes an api call to see if there is additional data about the sender to an Azure SQL database, and populates a view in outlook with that info, if it exists.

I'm not sure what technologies I should be using (I've never created an outlook extension), so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link will help you learn how to create an Outlook 2010\2013 Add-In using c#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

The below links will help connecting to SQL Azure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951633.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336243.aspx

Let me know if any further help is needed, Happy Coding !!